# AttributeError while loading tensorflow keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, attributeerror, tf.keras

I've build a tensorflow keras model for chatbot. But while loading the model it was return an error i don't know what to do and the error was pointing at the model loading. I don't now what was the cause

Here is my code:

```
From tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
Model = load_model('chatbot_model.h5')
Import json
Import random
Intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())
Words = pickle.load(open('words.pkl','rb'))
Classes = pickle.load(open('classes.pkl','rb'))
```

So, its always returning the error below
Which is:

```
AttributeError.     Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2524/2282111844.py in <module>
    1 from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
--->2 Model = load_model("chatbot.model.h5")
    3 Import json
    4 Import random
    5 intents = json.loads(open("intents.json").read())

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/keras/saving/save.py in loady_model(filepath, custom_objects,compile, options)

    204.  If (h5py is not None and
    205.       (Isinstance(filepath, h5py.file) or h5py.is_hdf5(filepath))):
--->206      return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    207. 
    208. 
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py in load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    180.    If model_config is None:
    181.       Raisw ValueError('No model found in config file.')
--->182.    Model_config = json_utils.decode(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
    183     model = model_config_lib.model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)


AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Please i need some help on how to solve thd error please!!!

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like the problem is happening at the point of loading the model (line 2). Is that model in the same directory/at the same level as the code being run? Maybe share the relevant parts of your directory structure.

Comment: The model is in the same directory

Comment: Looks like issue with `h5py` version. Whivh version of`h5py` are you using.Thanks!